# React Toolbox Tabs giving error when used within ThemeProvider

Tags: reactjs, react-toolbox

App.jsx is:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <div>
    <Tabs index={0}>
      <Tab label='Primary'><small>1Primary content</small></Tab>
      <Tab  label='Secondary'><small>Sec content</small></Tab>
    </Tabs>
    <Input label="test"/>
  </div>
</ThemeProvider>
```

Error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'pointer' of undefined Tabs.render @
>   line 240 var classNamePointer = (0,
>   _classnames4.default)(theme.pointer, _defineProperty({}, theme.disableAnimation, disableAnimatedBottomBorder));

Answer (score 0):

Yo should add forceRenderTabPanel={true} to the tabs as such: .
It will keep track of the state across all three tabs and not just the one you are on.